# Need an excel formula that reads corresponding row

Tags: excel-formula

Lets say Cell I9 is 52

Cell A16 to A75 is a number ...example A16 = 1, A17=2, A18=3 and so on to 60

Cells B16 to B75 is a date for each number

F9 - I am trying to make a formula that would display the corresponding date that equals I9.

Can someone help me out with this?

```
Estimated Completion Days   4
Estimated Date of Completion    

A        B
Day     Date
1     9/19/2017
2     9/20/2017
3     9/21/2017
4     9/22/2017
```

If the Estimated number of days = a certain value on the table, I would like for a formula I could put it another cell that displays the date for that number.

Comment: Can you post some sort of table which demonstrates what the problem is?  It is a bit hard to visualize so many cells.

Comment: So what code have you come up with so far? Or are you expecting someone else to do all the work?

Comment: Looking at your table - are you sure that's what you want?  By the looks of it you just want find the fourth day after a todays date - or maybe _x_ number of days after a specified date so `=today()+4` might be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *Estimated number of days* is in `Cell E16` and *Estimated Date of Completion* has to be displayed in `Cell E17` then enter the following formula in `Cell E17`

```
=VLOOKUP(E16,A16:B75,2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=INDEX(B16:B75,MATCH(E16,A16:A75,0))
```

where `A16:B75` is your data range.

[image]